# Labels too close and overlapping with the internal symbols in xy package

Tags: xy-pic, xymatrix

I have given an answer on a question with this MWE, and I am not see an evident hole  created when I insert a symbol into an arrow. The labels also overlapped to the symbols. How to solve the problem?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
 
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=4pc@C=4pc{ A \ar@{=}|{/}[r]^a \ar[d]_{c}|{\subset} & B 
\ar[d]^b|{\cong} \\
 C \ar[r]_d|{\cong} & D;}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very nice MWE! :-) I suggest you use `\mathstrut` -- where necessary, augmented with `\smash[t]` or `\smash[b]` -- and `\,` (thinspace) directives to fine-tune the placement of the symbols and letters.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \smash[t] and \smash[b] macros
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
 
\begin{document}
\xymatrix @R=4pc @C=4pc { 
  A \ar@{=}|{/}[r]^{a\smash[t]{\mathstrut}} % smashed \mathstrut
    \ar[d]_{c\,}|{\subset\mathstrut}    % full-height \mathstrut
& B \ar[d]^{\,b}|{\cong\mathstrut} \\   % full-height \mathstrut
  C \ar[r]_{d\smash[b]{\mathstrut}}|{\,\cong\,} % smashed \mathstrut
& D ;
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much...........................grazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee....accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I know you are a big fan of `xy`, so this is just for comparison with `tikz-cd`.

[image]

A new style is created for the special labels for use inside the arrow command: `\arrow[r, "<main label>"{special=<direction>:<secondary label>}]`, where `<direction>` can be provided as an angle or compass direction.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{special/.style={description, label={[label distance=-5pt, font=\scriptsize]#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep=1.5cm]
A\arrow[r, equals, "/"{special=90:$a$}]\arrow[d, "\subset"{special=180:$c$}] & B\arrow[d, "\cong"{special=0:$b$}]\\
C\arrow[r, "\cong"{special=270:$d$}] & D
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```